# Reading a CSV file with commas in a column

Tags: r, csv

I have a csv file with 6 columns and one of the columns has text separated by comma, e.g., BOLT, RD HD SQ SHORT NECK, METRIC.

When I read this file in R there is overflow from this column and subsequently data moves to a new line.

Below I am pasting few lines

> 014003051906,ETN5080 ,0450,BOLT KIT UPPER SHAFT WITH 5 SPEED,1.000,F
>   014003051906,ETN5967 ,0460,SENSOR SENSOR FH BACKSHAFT SPEED,1.000,F
>   014003051906,ETN64267 ,0470,TILT UNIT SENSOR,1.000,F
>
> 014003065376,03M7184 ,0020,BOLT - M 8.0 X 1.250 X 20.0 -
>   8.8-Zinc,4.000,G 014003065376,03M7386 ,0090,BOLT, RD HD SQ SHORT NECK, METRIC,18.000,G 014003065376,14M7296 ,0090,NUT, METRIC, HEX
>   FLANGE,14.000,G

The last two line is where the problem lies. "NUT, METRIC, HEX FLANGE" should come under one variable.

How can this be resolved?

Comment: How did you come across the data? (saved as CSV from Excel?)  The best solution is to request the data be saved in a format where either the data are quoted or using a different delimiter.

Comment: @Benjamin I'd thought of the same. But unfortunately this is the only source we have.

Comment: You could go with regular expressions

Comment: @Benjamin Excel is rude in many ways, but it's at least polite enough to put comma-containing strings inside quotes.

Comment: @HongOoi my mistake, and my apologies to Excel.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
data <- readLines(con = textConnection("014003051906,ETN5080 ,0450,BOLT KIT UPPER SHAFT WITH 5 SPEED,1.000,F
014003051906,ETN5967 ,0460,SENSOR SENSOR FH BACKSHAFT SPEED,1.000,F
014003051906,ETN64267 ,0470,TILT UNIT SENSOR,1.000,F

014003065376,03M7184 ,0020,BOLT - M 8.0 X 1.250 X 20.0 - 8.8-Zinc,4.000,G
014003065376,03M7386 ,0090,BOLT, RD HD SQ SHORT NECK, METRIC,18.000,G
014003065376,14M7296 ,0090,NUT, METRIC, HEX FLANGE,14.000,G"))

pattern <- "^([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*),([^,]*),([^,]*)$"

library(stringr)
str_match(data, pattern)[, - 1]
#      [,1]           [,2]        [,3]   [,4]                                     [,5]     [,6]
# [1,] "014003051906" "ETN5080 "  "0450" "BOLT KIT UPPER SHAFT WITH 5 SPEED"      "1.000"  "F" 
# [2,] "014003051906" "ETN5967 "  "0460" "SENSOR SENSOR FH BACKSHAFT SPEED"       "1.000"  "F" 
# [3,] "014003051906" "ETN64267 " "0470" "TILT UNIT SENSOR"                       "1.000"  "F" 
# [4,] NA             NA          NA     NA                                       NA       NA  
# [5,] "014003065376" "03M7184 "  "0020" "BOLT - M 8.0 X 1.250 X 20.0 - 8.8-Zinc" "4.000"  "G" 
# [6,] "014003065376" "03M7386 "  "0090" "BOLT, RD HD SQ SHORT NECK, METRIC"      "18.000" "G" 
# [7,] "014003065376" "14M7296 "  "0090" "NUT, METRIC, HEX FLANGE"                "14.000" "G"
```

**Edit:**
Regex explanations for beginners, in plain words so please forgive inaccuracies:

- Initial `^` and terminal `$` mean start and end of string.
- Parens are for grouping (groups that `str_match()` will extract).
- `.` means any character, and `.*` means any amount of any characters.
- `[^,]` means any character that is not a comma.

When put together, it means : `start of string` - `substring without a comma` - `comma` (repeated 3 times) - `substring possibly containing commas` - `comma` - `substring without a comma` - `comma` - `substring without a comma` - `end of string`, and only the parenthesized groups are extracted.

Comment: Expanding your idea, you could add commas around the 4th field and call `read.csv`: `read.csv(text=gsub("^([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,)(.*)(,[^,]*,[^,]*)$","\\1\"\\2\"\\3",data),header=FALSE)`

Comment: @Apom I am new to regex, could you please explain the regex part?