# R fails to import flat file with unescaped quote inside field

Tags: r, import, txt

I am trying to import a large .txt file that uses |,| to separate columns. The raw data looks like this:
[image]

The original .txt file has 593 118 lines (entries). However, using my import line I can only import 191 838 lines, and a lot of these lines are imported incorrectly. The imported file looks like this (e.g., lines 189880:189889 are imported correctly, the others are not):

[image]

The number of columns is correct using this code, it only fails to import all rows correctly. In addition, when using my import code, the following warning message pops up:

```
Test<-read.csv("test2.txt", header = FALSE, sep = ",", quote = "|")
Warning message:
In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  EOF within quoted string
```

I can import 544 605 lines using the following import command (switching the quote:"|" and sep=","):

```
Test<-read.csv("test2.txt", header = FALSE, sep = “|", quote = “,”)
```

Only now, the whole file looks messy, and the data are in the wrong columns and a wrong number of columns are created (41 instead of 39):
[image]

Does someone know how to import this .txt file correctly?

Comment: Could you include lines 189889 and 189890 from the text file, as text (not screenshot), in your question? (redacting confidential information if any, of course)

Comment: @Aurèle thank you for your comment. I have uploaded a small sample .txt file with an error upload. It only contains public info.

Comment: The file contains this field on line 403 `|Cardlytics, Inc.Strike price: $1.11 | NeitherExpires: 01/25/2021|` with an enclosed `|` that is not meant as a quote. That's what breaks things I guess

Comment: Hi @Mike! If the separator is |,|, why don't you replace this separator with a more usual one, like: , (comma), ;, \t, among others?

Comment: Maybe you could adapt this answer to your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/41613610/6197649 (similar issue with separator instead of quotes, could also be solved with regex I think).   Or fix the problem at the source, escaping the enclosed `|` like `\|`

Comment: @Aurèle Excellent find, I think that that is the problem. Regarding your helpful regex post, which regex statement should I use for my file? Altering the [^,] and using ^([^|]*),([^|]*) (for 39 columns) results in a Large matrix in my R environment with only NA’s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data.table automatically resolves the issue, while displaying an informative message:

```r
library(data.table)

DT <- fread(
  "data/test3.txt",
  header = FALSE, 
  quote = "|"
)
```

```
Warning message:
In fread("data/test3.txt", header = FALSE, quote = "|") :
  Found and resolved improper quoting out-of-sample. First healed line 403: <<|B160001953|,|S|,|N00035516|,|16|,|Y|,| |,| |,|Cardlytics, Inc.Strike price: $1.11 | NeitherExpires: 01/25/2021|,|Cardlytics Inc|,||,||,||,||,||,||,||,||,||,|I |,,| |,| |,| |,| |,| |,| |,| |,|p |,| |,| |,| |,.0000,| |,| |,| |,,||,||,| |>>. If the fields are not quoted (e.g. field separator does not appear within any field), try quote="" to avoid this warning.
```

```
DT[403]
```

```
           V1 V2        V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
1: B160001953  S N00035516 16  Y      
                                                                 V8             V9
1: Cardlytics, Inc.Strike price: $1.11 | NeitherExpires: 01/25/2021 Cardlytics Inc
   V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23 V24 V25 V26 V27 V28 V29
1:                                      I   NA                              p     
   V30 V31 V32 V33 V34 V35 V36 V37 V38 V39
1:           0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a working- and very user friendly option.